# Extranet vs VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, intranet, private-network

What's the difference between an extranet and a VPN, and what common uses does each one serve? What technology stacks are often use to implement each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extranet is outside the firewall, private not public ([DMZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29)), but only open to certain people/companies/oranizations.... https, instead of a vpn client connection.

Intranet is inside the firewall, and private, sealed off from the internet. You can use VPN to access the intranet securely though.

Comment: Ahhh, so vpn is actually a secure, binary *protocol* and not a type of network? That makes sense!

Comment: VPN connects a network (your computer from home for example), and will use the public Internet as a backbone to another private network (your office's network) using a secure encrypted tunnel. Thus it will seem you are at your office on the network but you are really not there (just virtually). VPN is not a protocol, though it uses several to achieve this connection.

Answer (score 5):

They are names for very different concepts.

A VPN is a "virtual private network", a piece of software that creates an encrypted communication between two (potentially) far-away computers such that nobody in between can see the contents of the communication.

An extranet is something of a made-up term, referring to a web site that a company publishes for the benefit of its vendors, partners, or customers. The name "extranet" was derived from "intranet", which is a web site that's intended for use only within a company. That term itself was sort of perverted from "Internet", which is literally a network of networks (web sites came around long after the Internet per se was created).

So an extranet is really a web site with a specific purpose. It's not a technology for setting up communications between computers like a VPN is.

Comment: OK - so the VPN is a private *intranet*, but one that can span large geographic locations and even authenticate connections from the outside; and an extranet sounds like the same thing as an intranet but one that is configured to allow connections from vendors, business partners, etc. Is this the gist of it?

Comment: VPN is a secure encrypted connection into a private network.

Answer (score 2):

A virtual private network (VPN) is a private network of computers linked using a secure “tunnel” connection over a public network such as the Internet. An extranet is a private intranet based on Internet and World Wide Web technology and standards that is accessible to authorized outsiders. A VPN is a method of securing a network, whereas an extranet describes a type of network in terms of its users, in this case, a firm and authorized vendors or partners.